# SwiftUI Button as EditButton

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

How I can use a button like `EditButton`?
Or how I can use a button to active edit mode from list?
Or how I can change the name from `EditButton` "edit" / "done"?

Comment: You may want to clarify your question. Are you referring (only) to the title of the button? Or do you want to know how to enter the edit mode of a List? Or both? (In that case you may want to create a separate question). Plus what have you tried so far? Can you share some code?

Comment: I mean both.. i want active the edit mode for the list with a button like editbutton, I know i can use the editbutton but I want use other designe.. not („edit“/„done“) I want rename this or take a image, so I have to use a button.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, please take a look.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The implementation below replaces `EditButton`'s functionality with a `Button`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isEditing = false
    @State var selection = Set<String>()

    var names = ["Karl", "Hans", "Faustao"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(names, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Names")
                .environment(\.editMode, .constant(self.isEditing ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive)).animation(Animation.spring())
                Button(action: {
                    self.isEditing.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit")
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 40)
                }
                .background(Color.yellow)
            }
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

> Result

[image: result]

However, by doing so, selection handling needs to be implemented by our own (which may or may not be an issue).

Unfortunately there isn't much documentation around that at this point:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/3367016-init

Comment: the smooth animation can u active with this code
 .environment(\.editMode, .constant(self.isEditing ? EditMode.active : EditMode.inactive)).animation(Animation.spring())

Comment: Great! Nice tip on ".animation...". I didn't know about that. I updated the answer to include this info.  Please accept it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219412 Thanks.

Comment: This is so helpful. I've had an issue for months where an EditButton would stop working after closing a modal sheet. It's some sort of combination of the EditButton, the edit mode state, and the order in which redraw on screen when closing the modal. I replaced the edit mode and button with this and it's finally working as desired. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Using the .constant() binding in the .environment() view modifier caused crashes in my code, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68938630/1085556

Answer (score 13):

Here's a way to preserve `EditButton`'s functionality while still observing changes.

```
EditButton()
    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
        // Do your thing
    })
```

This works for every view on which you want to observe taps.

Answer (score 7):

There is a better way to do this in Beta 5, where you can grab the `@Environment` binding directly (also better to make this a navigation bar item):

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditableListView: View {

    @State var items: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
    @State var selections: Set<String> = []

    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode: Binding<EditMode>

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self, selection: $selections) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                self.editMode?.value.toggle()
            }) {
                Text(self.editMode?.value == .active ? "Done" : "Edit")
            }
        )
        .animation(.default)
    }
}

extension EditMode {

    mutating func toggle() {
        self = self == .active ? .inactive : .active
    }
}
```

[image: EditableListAnimation]

Comment: it does not work for me.. when i click the button then he dont do anything

Comment: as solo View.
if i do it as second view and open ur code as navigationlink then its ur code well.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As for Xcode 13, there seems to be some update. I test the following code works.

```
@State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
@State var isEditing = false

List {
    // (your list code here)
}.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)

Button(action: {
    isEditing.toggle()
    editMode = isEditing ? .active : .inactive
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I was even able to use this method with `editMode` as an @ObservedObject property in my own controller object outside of SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a normal button like the following :

```
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack{
        Button(action: {
            editMode?.wrappedValue.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text(editButtinTxt)
        })
    })
```

and the text :

```
var editBtnTxt : String {
    
    if let isEditing = editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing {
        return isEditing ? "Done" : "Edit"
    }else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

and don't forget

```
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
```